# How to clear and add SortDescriptor to a Telerik DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, telerik

I am developing a WPF application that uses Telerik controls (http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-sorting-programmatic.html).
I want to clear the sorting descriptor and then I want to add it again.

I clear the sortingDescriptors:

```
 grdPatients.SortDescriptors.Clear();
```

then I add the sortingdescriptor with the following code:

```
       grdPatients.SortDescriptors.Add(new Telerik.Windows.Data.SortDescriptor()
        {
          Member = "Patient.Name",
          SortDirection = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
        });
```

but the sorting is not applied.

Am I missing something?

SOLVED: The problem was at the Sort Descriptor Member :"Patient.Name"

Comment: What is the type of each item bound to the grid? Is it a `Patient` or something that has a `Patient` property?

Comment: The itemssource is binded to a collection of Patients

Comment: Ok so you want to put `Member = "Name"` then - not `Patient.Name`, the member property specifies a binding path (with the current DataContext at the root), which with `Patient.Name` would be looking for a property called `Patient` on `Patient` and a member called `Name` on the resultant object. You want `DataContext.Name`, not `DataContext.Patient.Name`

Comment: Tried with Member = "Name" still not working

Comment: Can you post the `Patient` class definition (just the fields/properties will do)?

Comment: Charleh was right, thanks